# How can I win on level 76

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I am in level 76 of Candy Crush Saga and I brought down all ingredients but they are still there. How can I destroy them?

The 3 ingredients still appearing

Comment: What game are you asking about?

Comment: Hi there. This has been put on hold because it's not answerable until you add what game this is. Use the **edit** link below the question to fix it up, and it'll get un-held so people can start submitting answers.

Comment: i assume this is candy crush

Comment: for sure its candycrush

Comment: Since candies are randomly generated, it is hard to say ***exactly*** how to beat that level.  Just keep trying until you get it.

Answer (score 2):

Level 76 has three boxes - top-left, bottom-left and right. The ingredients need to pass down from the bottom-left, through the right, then to the bottom of the top-left box to be collected - the green arrows at the bottom of that box indicate this is the area they are collected from.

There's a chance you may not have any matches available in the top-right box, in which case you'll need to use a striped or spotted candy in another box to remove those in the top-right box that are in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Graham's helpful answer, if you can make a striped/wrapped candy combo once or twice in this level you'll really give yourself an easier time. Don't get caught up too much in focusing on the bottom left portion, just work on the right side as much as possible and look for special candy combos.

In the future, if you have any trouble with CC levels, take a look at websites like ReadyGamer, the King forums, or other dedicated sources for level tips.